# h2o ec2 max use of cores

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, h2o, rstudio-server

Does h2o make use of all the available cores on an ec2 server (not instance) on the fly?

I ask because I run several instances of rstudio on ec2. Some are bigger, some are smaller. My spaghetti code gets transferred from one window to another.

When setting cores on a t2.micro

```
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
```

It will connect to the "max" number of cores I explicitly created for the instance. However,

```
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   0.23 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    15 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  1
```

Seems to suggest that there are more cores available.

I noticed this when I transferred code over from another instance with 16 cores to the instance with 1 core.

```
h2o.init(nthreads = 16)
```

This code created

```
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   0.23 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    15 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  15
```

Another example, on the 16 core instance, I was curious, and set nthreads=128, but it maxes out at 40.

Is h2o grabbing extra allowable cores on the fly? I ask because this would be much easier and quicker than setting up a cluster.

Comment: The t2.micro instance class is a single core machine.  Compare the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on different instance class machines.  Beyond that, I'm not really sure what's being asked, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, t2.micro is a single core instance, so the `H2O cluster allowed cores:  1` is correct.  However, it looks like you are running into bug in reporting the number of `H2O cluster allowed cores` with virtual machines (like those used in EC2) that was documented [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2775).  This was fixed on 4/1/16 and so it should be fixed in the latest stable release.  Download the [latest stable](http://www.h2o.ai/download/) of H2O and try again -- if you still see `H2O cluster total cores:  15`, post a comment here and we will re-open the ticket.